# 'Unknown field for WriteResult: Collection', exception caused when creating sub collection for firestore db

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Here's the syntax I used, I encounter an exception when the third line is executed.

```
fire_client = firestore.Client()
def_ref = fire_client.collection('collection_parent').document('document1').set({"key":"value"})
msg_ref = def_ref.collection('collection_child').document('document2').set({"key1":"value1"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.set()` method returns a [`WriteResult`](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/types.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.types.WriteResult) that does not have a `collection()` method. So `def_ref.collection(...)` throws that exception. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
fire_client = firestore.Client()
def_ref = fire_client.collection('collection_parent').document('document1')
def_ref.set({"key":"value"})

msg_ref = def_ref.collection('collection_child').document('document2')
msg_ref.set({"key1":"value1"})
```